# C++ Open a stream on a socket fd

Tags: c++, sockets, io, stream, file-descriptor

I would like to open a stream on a sockect's fd, to read and write on it, but without using C functions, like `open()` `read()` or `write()`.

I watched around `fstream` but apparently nothing to do what I want.

Any ideas or suggestions ?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for something like [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html)? Among other things, it provides iostream-ish wrappers for sockets.

Comment: Your solution looks nice and could help me. But that's for a school's projest and I'm not allowed to use Boost Librairies.

Comment: Then your options are limited. You cannot use the ordinary standard `fstream` on sockets, so you would have to write your own C++ wrapper which uses those C functions internally.

Comment: Yes this is what I will definitely do. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

it could be done, I have seen it before, I have tried to do it for a buffer, to stream things to a buffer that later can be used to be sent to the

> write()

system call

take a look at [this](https://github.com/karshan/sockstream), which is a custom made